# SQLAlchemy filter() return value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having one of those days.

I want to check if a particular row exists in my DB, and if it does, return True.
If not, return False.

A brief example:

```
contact_object = Contact.query.filter(Contact.user_id == user_id and Contact.contact_id == contact_id).first()
```

This should return exactly 1 row (which it does). Here's what I would like:

```
if contact_object:
    print "YEY, it was found"
else:
    print "Nope, not found"
```

However, contact_object always returns `True`, and I always get a "YEY, it was found"

(Note that `user_id` and `contact_id` are variables that I have defined previously.)

How do I check for a row not found versus a row found? I read the relevant documentation to no avail...but I feel like I'm surely missing something simple?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's certainly strange that first() would give you a True value even if nothing was found... But you might be interested in using .one() instead, which expects one and only one row returned. If nothing was found, it will raise a NoResultFound exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can use `and` in a filter expression in SQL Alchemy that way:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators

```
contact_object = Contact.query \
    .filter(Contact.user_id == user_id) \
    .filter(Contact.contact_id == contact_id) \
    .first()
```

Comment: Now I feel totally daft, but relieved that I got it to work. So thank you.